# Changing GL lines via Custom GL Plugin in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Some of the GL lines show up without entity names in them:
[image]

I'm trying to add the name if it is missing via the custom GL lines plugin.

I already have the following code:

```
var standardLinesCount = standardLines.getCount();
for(var i = 0; i < standardLinesCount; i++) {
    var entity = transactionRecord.getFieldValue('entity');
    var line = standardLines.getLine(i);
    
}
```

I do now know however how I can now use the value in the 'entity' variable to set the name field of the 'line'. I checked the documentation, but could not find the function to do this. Does anyone know how I can get this done?

Answer (score 2):

Standard lines on the GL Impact are immutable. You can call API functions to get values from the standardLines object, but you cannot write to it.

NetSuite's default functionality should be automatically entering the entity value in the Name field of the GL Impact for any payable or receivable entries. If you are trying to record the entity value on a line that is not related to the entity from an accounting perspective, then you will need to write custom lines reversing the standard line and recreating it with your specified entity value. However, I encourage you to look into your reporting options to accomplish what you need via standard functionality, rather than trying to customize the GL.

If you decide to continue down the custom GL path, this will set the value of the entity on custom GL impact lines:

```
var newLine = customLines.addNewLine();
if(entity){newLine.setEntityId(entity);}
```

Other function calls to set the account, amount, etc. for custom lines are listed in the API documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4072822491.html